# Retrieving all customer records, including those without associated emails, using SQL

Tags: mysql, email, relational-database, left-join, entity-relationship

I have two tables in my database: customers and emails. The emails table stores email records for each customer, where a customer can have zero, one, or multiple email records.

I want to write a SQL query that retrieves all customer records from the customers table, including those customers who do not have any associated email records in the emails table.

Currently, I am using the following query:

```
SELECT customers.*, emails.email 
FROM customers 
LEFT JOIN emails ON emails.record_id = customers.id
```

However, this query only returns the customer records that have at least one email record associated with them. I want to modify this query to include all customer records, even if they do not have any email records.

Could you please suggest the necessary modifications to achieve the desired result?

Comment: post ddl for both tables

Comment: Are you sure the result is incorrect? You are using a left join and no constraints on customers so there is no way for a record from customers table not to be returned.

Comment: I'm unable to upload an image otherwise I would have posted the ERD for this, is there any way to do so... @jedrzej.kurylo

Comment: basically the query is incomplete, I thought this would explain the problem, but when I watched closely, the problem lies in the constraints

Comment: dont upload an image put the table definition text. `show create table customers; show create table emails;`

Comment: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/W8BNSxC.png?1)

Comment: ok so why are you joining on record_id

Comment: the record_id is basically customer_id, also the `user_type` can have (`customer` , `employee` ...) and `type` can have different departments like ('Call centre', 'Accounts' ... ) so the actual query is.

Comment: `select customers.*,emails.email from emails LEFT JOIN customers on customers.id = emails.record_id WHERE emails.type = 'Call Centre' and emails.user_type = 'customer'`

Comment: and I'm unable to get the customers that doesn't have any emails yet

Comment: you didnt mention the where clause in the question..  if there are no emails in the email table for the customer the where will evaluate null = 'Call Centre' as false.. also the diagram is misleading

Comment: yes, because I thought that have nothing to do with the problem, but now I understand that its causing the problem

Comment: i recommend you correct the diagram also

Comment: ok,you are right, but can you please suggest the solution...

Comment: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/nH8v1Kt.png?1)

Comment: one way : `select customers.*,emails.email from emails LEFT JOIN customers on customers.id = emails.record_id WHERE coalesce(emails.type, 'Call Centre') = 'Call Centre' and coalesce(emails.user_type, 'customer') = 'customer'`

Comment: It didn't worked, I'm still getting the same result

Comment: ok then your going to need to create a fiddle with some sample data exhibiting the problem

Comment: The problem might be in your WHERE clause, which is filtering your left table's records.. try
`SELECT customers.*, emails.email from customers LEFT JOIN emails on customers.id = emails.record_id WHERE (user_type = 'customer' OR user_type is null) and (type='Call Centre' or type is null)`

Comment: I've got the expected result from this query but I'm getting repeated records @sohaiby

Comment: and can you please post it as an answer ? @sohaiby

Comment: There might be multiple records in your Email table against one CustomerID.. try using distinct
`SELECT Distinct customers.*, emails.email from customers LEFT JOIN emails on customers.id = emails.record_id WHERE (user_type = 'customer' OR user_type is null) and (type='Call Centre' or type is null)`

Comment: it solved my problem... you may post it as an answer.. thanks @sohaiby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be in your WHERE clause, which is filtering your left (Customer) table's records. Also, If you have multiple records in Email table against one CustomerID, then you must use distinct.

```
SELECT 
    Distinct customers.*, emails.email 
FROM customers 
LEFT JOIN 
    emails ON customers.id = emails.record_id 
WHERE 
    (user_type = 'customer' OR user_type is null) 
    AND 
    (type='Call Centre' or type is null)
```